# Silly Error calculating eigenvalues of a 3x3?

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok so I am doing a standard diagonalization procedure on a Hamiltonian, and I can't see what sort of silly mistake I have made. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My matrix reads:

\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & 0 \\
 b & a & b \\
 0 & a & b \\
\end{array}

so I start by taking DET[Matrix]=0 as usual.

I write :
$$
0\text{}=\text{}a-\lambda *\left[(a-\lambda )^2-b^2\right]
\text{}-\text{}b*[b (a-\lambda )]\text{}\\0=-b^2 (a-\lambda )-b^2 (a-\lambda )+(a-\lambda )^3\\\text{}0=\text{}a-\lambda *\left[(a-\lambda )^2-2 b^2\right]
$$

From the first term I say E1 = a.

Next I factor the $\left[(a-\lambda )^2-2 b^2\right]$ term to give:
$$
\left[(a-\lambda )^2-2 b^2\right]\\=a^2-2 a \lambda -2 b^2+\lambda ^2\\=\left(-a+\sqrt{2} b+\lambda \right) \left(-a-\sqrt{2} b+\lambda \right)
$$

From which I write E2 = $a-\sqrt{2} b$ and E3= $a+\sqrt{2} b$

However when I go to mathematica to verify my results I get something which looks much more complicated:

Input: Eigenvalues[mat]

Output:

{Root[b^3 + (a^2 + a b - b^2) #1 + (-2 a - b) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1],

Root[b^3 + (a^2 + a b - b^2) #1 + (-2 a - b) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2],

Root[b^3 + (a^2 + a b - b^2) #1 + (-2 a - b) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}

Does anyone see any errors with my method of diagonalizing by hand?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you typo the last row of your matrix swapping $a$ and $b$?. For me, Mathematica gives the expected hand obtained results.

Comment: Victor!!!!!! you're totally right, it was meant to read 0,b,a for last row. Thanks so much man, sometimes it just helps to have a second pair of eyes, or someone to talk the process over with, and I am on spring break right now so I lack the ability to discuss with peers. Thanks again